ПРоблема с даунгрейдом Maven в IntelliJ IDEA
Пытаюсь подключить удаленный репозиторий, Maven пишет, что начиная с версии 3.8.1 он больше не разрешает использовать http-репозитории. Переключиться на https я не могу, использовать уловку с зеркалами у меня не получилось, решил попробовать даунгрейднуть Maven. Вручную скачал, установил, прописал в системных переменных: система говорит, что у меня теперь Maven 3.6.3.
Но в IDEA Maven установлен как плагин, она видит только его и больше ничего, если в настройках плагина указать старую версию, Идея ее не видит.



пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
